# CUDA function call from other .cpp file that contains the same header file

Tags: c++, cuda, header

I have two files utilCUDA.cu and util.cpp. They both include util.h. "add" is declared in util.h and defined in util.cpp. "add" calls "addCUDA" to add the two vectors. Please don't mind the approach, it's just meant as a test project.

The error is:

```
util.cpp: In function ‘void add(double*, double*, double*, int)’:
util.cpp:5:20: error: ‘addCUDA’ was not declared in this scope
```

Is there anyway I can call "addCUDA" in "add"?

util.h:

```c
#ifndef __UTIL_H__
#define __UTIL_H__


#include <stdio.h>
void add(double *a, double *b, double *c, int size);
void printVec(double *v, int size);

#endif
```

util.cpp:

```c
#include "util.h"

void add(double *a, double *b, double * c, int N)
{
    addCUDA(a,b,c,N);
}
void printVec(double *v, int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%f ", v[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

utilCUDA.h:

```c
#ifndef __UTILCUDA_H__
#define __UTILCUDA_H__
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include "util.h"

__global__ void myAdd(double *a, double *b, double *c, int size);
void addCUDA (double *a, double *b, double *c, int size);
#endif
```

utilCUDA.cu:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "utilCUDA.h"
#define THREAD_PER_BLOCK 128
__global__ void myAdd( double *a, double *b, double *c, int size ) {
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;//blockIdx.x;    // this thread handles the data at its thread id
    if (tid < size)
        c[tid] = a[tid] + b[tid];
}

void addCUDA(double *a, double *b, double *c, int size)
{
    printf("CUDA called\n");
    double *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_a, size * sizeof(double) );
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_b, size * sizeof(double) );
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_c, size * sizeof(double) ); 

    cudaMemcpy( dev_a, a, size * sizeof(double),
                cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaMemcpy( dev_b, b, size * sizeof(double),
                cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    myAdd<<<(size - 1)/THREAD_PER_BLOCK + 1,THREAD_PER_BLOCK>>>( dev_a, dev_b, dev_c,size );

    cudaMemcpy( c, dev_c, size * sizeof(double),
                  cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
    cudaFree( dev_a );
    cudaFree( dev_b );
    cudaFree( dev_c );
}
```

test.cpp:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "util.h"

#ifdef USE_CUDA
    #include "utilCUDA.h"
#endif

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int size = atoi(argv[1]);

    double *a, *b, *c;// *cBase;
    int j;
    a = (double*)malloc(size*sizeof(double));
    b = (double*)malloc(size*sizeof(double));
    c = (double*)malloc(size*sizeof(double));    

    srand(time(NULL));
        for(j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            a[j] = rand() % 10;
            b[j] = rand() % 10;
        }

    printVec(a,size);
    printVec(b,size);
#ifdef USE_CUDA    
    addCUDA(a,b,c,size);

#endif

#ifdef NO_CUDA
    add(a,b,c,size);
#endif
    printVec(c,size);
    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```c
NVCC_RESULT := $(shell which nvcc 2> NULL)
NVCC_TEST := $(notdir $(NVCC_RESULT))
CFLAGS=-c -Wall

CUDAFLAGS=-c

CUDA_INCLUDE =
OBJ=test.o util.o 
ifeq ($(NVCC_TEST),nvcc)
    CUDACC := nvcc
    CC := g++
    OBJ+=utilCUDA.o
    CUDA_INCLUDE += -I /usr/local/cuda-5.5/include
    CCFLAGS := -DUSE_CUDA
else
    CUDACC := g++
    CC := g++
    CCFLAGS := -DNO_CUDA

endif


all: test

test: $(OBJ)    
    $(CUDACC) $(CCFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o test

ifeq ($(NVCC_TEST),nvcc)
utilCUDA.o: utilCUDA.cu utilCUDA.h
    $(CUDACC) $(CCFLAGS) $(CUDAFLAGS) utilCUDA.cu
endif

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $*.cpp $(CUDA_INCLUDE)
clean:
    rm -rf *.o test
```

Comment: Did you define both functions in the ".h file"?

Comment: No, the functions are defined in their corresponding files.

Comment: You question isn't clear (to me at least). Can you provide a minimal self-contained example code that others can compile, along with a description of expected vs. actual behavior? Are you getting compilation errors, run-time errors, crashes?

Comment: Try adding the function headers to the .h file. (a function header is just the function declaration without the body - ie void func(int a, int b);)

Comment: @njuffa: I just editted the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

util.cpp calls `addCUDA` but you haven't indicated where to find it. (i.e. you've provided no "declaration" of the function in that scope.)

move this line:

```
void addCUDA (double *a, double *b, double *c, int size);
```

from utilCUDA.h to util.h

this really has nothing to do with CUDA.